# ¿Como calcular la resta de un arreglo llenado por el usuario desde el ultimo numero hasta el primero?

Tags: java, array

Me podrian ayudar con un problema por favor: Crear un arreglo del tamaño que decida el usuario, llenar el arreglo con números ingresados por el usuario, después calcular la resta desde el ultimo numero ingresado hasta el primero

```
package programa.pkg79;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Programa79 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        int tam, resta=0;
        System.out.println("Cuantos numeros quieres ingresar:");
        tam  = lector.nextInt();
        int arre[] = new int[tam];

        System.out.println("Ingrese los numeros:");
        for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
            arre[i]=lector.nextInt();
        }

        //aquí estoy perdido no se como hacer la resta :(
    }    
}
```

Comment: listo, pon el código que tienes hasta ahora

Comment: @RicardoRamssSeplvedaBecerra mostrar codigo en los comentarios no es adecuado, tu puedes [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/120250/edit) cuando desees para añadir detalles.

Comment: ok gracias jeje esque soy principiante gracias por el consejo

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int tamanio, resta = 0, aux = 0;
System.out.println("¿Que tamaño desea?");
tamanio = sc.nextInt();
int vector[] = new int[tamanio];

for(int i = 0; i < tamanio; i++){
    System.out.println(" posicion # " + i + "\nIngrese dato");
    vector[i] = sc.nextInt();
    if(i == (tamanio - 1)){
        aux = vector[i]; //guarda el ultimo dato ingresado
    }
} 

//resta del ultimo ingresado hasta el primero
for(int x = (tamanio - 2); x >= 0; x--) { //empieza desde el penultimo dato, recorriendo hasta el primero
    resta = aux - vector[x]; // se resta del ultimo ingresado al antepenultimo
    aux = resta; //toma el resultado anterior, para volverse a restar 
 }

System.out.println("La resta es"+resta);
```

Comment: asi se puede realizar

Comment: gracias :) Stany

Comment: Sería bueno @Stany que pudieras explicarle al OP algo del código que has colocado, así quedaría la respuesta mucho mas completa, saludos !